# Execution of Groovy code in java at runtime

Tags: java, dynamic, groovy, runtime, eval

Is it possible to execute groovy code dynamically loaded in java application.
For example there is a database table which contains small pieces of groovy code, like:

```
def test(${val_to_insert_from_java}){
    if (${val_to_insert_from_java} > 10){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Where `${val_to_insert_from_java}` is a placeholder for some real value which gonna be inserted during execution of java code, like:

```
String groovyFuncSource = getFromDb();
groovyFuncSource.replace(${val_to_insert_from_java}, 9);
Object result = <evaluate somehow groovyFuncSource>;
```

Is there is a way to evaluate such piece of Groovy code? Or may be you advise me some other approach how to implemnt this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

See the link http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

You may want to use caution with this approach, because executing code stored in a database will introduce security flaws in your application.  For example, some code maliciously inserted as text in your database could do ... almost anything unless you're checking it.

Comment: When executing untrusted code, it is better to work with some sandbox, like [groovy-sandbox](http://groovy-sandbox.kohsuke.org/)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be to use JavaScript instead of Groovy. Why? Because the [Rhino JavaScript engine already comes with the JDK](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/). So if you aren't already using Groovy in your projects, it's one less dependency.

Comment: Hm, nice idea considering that I haven't used Groovy in project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From Java 6 you can use [Java Scripting API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JSR+223+Scripting+with+Groovy) to do that. Java scripting API allows you to use various scripting languages within Java apps.

You can find more about Java Scripting [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Groovy script engine to evaluate Groovy source code at execution time - and of course that source code can be the result of string replacements.

From what I remember, there are various ways you can accomplish this, which will have different pros and cons.

<plug>
See chapter 11 of [Groovy in Action](http://manning.com/koenig/) for more details.
</plug>